# How to get duplicate values and their indexes of a serie with pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

Fzytion_val = [13055, 13563, 13867, 14696, 15460, 15311, 15311, 15603, 15603, 15861, 16807, 16807, 16919, 16388, 16388, 15433, 15497, 15145, 15163, 15163, 15984, 15984, 16859, 16859, 18150, 18970, 18970, 19328, 19337, 18876]
vc = pd.Series(Fzytion_val)
df =vc[vc.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()
```

I get the duplicate values

```
 [15311, 15311, 15603, 15603, 16807, 16807, 16388, 16388, 15163, 15163, 15984, 15984, 16859, 16859, 18970, 18970]
```

But I also want the indexes of this values and keep them in another list

`[5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26]`

The function duplicated returns just an array of boolean values, so is there another way in pandas to get the indexes ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create variable `s` for filtered `Series` and then convert index and values to lists:

```
s = vc[vc.duplicated(keep=False)]
L1 = s.index.tolist()
L2 = s.tolist()
```

Alternative (should be faster) is first convert to `numpy array` and then to `list`s:

```
L1 = s.index.values.tolist()
L2 = s.values.tolist()
```

---

```
print (L1)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26]
print (L2)
[15311, 15311, 15603, 15603, 16807, 16807, 16388, 16388, 15163, 
 15163, 15984, 15984, 16859, 16859, 18970, 18970]
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!